# - IOException AMC java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching api.mitel-amc.com found

Tags: ssl, dns

I am trying to access this site x.com from my local development setup.

**I have added the respective domain and ip to the "etc/hosts" file but when trying to get connected to the domain specified in the "etc/hosts". I get this below error from backend.** I am using apache tomcat 7.0.92 and getting this below error while trying to connect to the domain specified in "etc/hosts". **I am able to ping the domain in my laptop terminal window.**

**ERROR:-- IOException AMC java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching api.mitel-amc.com found.**

***Is there is any other place where I need to add this host or is there is a possibility that older SSL certificate with older host name is being used?
Is there is any key value generated in some other files for the entries which are added in the "etc/hosts" file.***

I am using MacBook Pro and OS is macOS Mojave and **I have formatted my system a few days back and again reinstalled all the development software after that only it is showing this error**.

Answer (score 2):

The error is about the SSL certificate, it seems you are making an https call, and there doesn't seem to be any SSL certificate associated with your host.